# Find out if Assignment has been sent for Approval - Project Online (REST or JSOM)

Tags: project-server, sharepoint-rest-api, ms-project, project-online

I need to figure out if the assignment was sent for approval in Project Online, using REST or JSOM

Answer (score 0):

I have not meet exact end-point which matches your requirement, but you can do a workaround with below;

JSOM

```
var value = PS.StatusAssignment.get_isConfirmed();
```

REST

```
GET http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/ProjectServer/EnterpriseResources('resourceid')/Assignments('assignmentid')/isConfirmed
```